# Can I publish my game on google play or are there copyrights that stop me

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, chat

I am currently developing a fps game with unity and I wanted to implement a chat. I searched for tutorials on chats on YouTube but couldn't find any good ones that worked. I finally found a simple chat in the asset store: [Simple Chat](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/19573). I changed minimal things such as colours and sizes.
 I added it in my game and I now want to know if i could publish it onto google play and commercialize it or if there were copyrights that stop me.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about copyright and legal issues instead of directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anything on the asset store, ***anything*** that you *acquire through the store*--free or otherwise--is yours to use in your project and publish.

Some assets may have some limitations on them that may restrict how many projects its used in, or how many "seats" you need to own (if specified, usually 1 purchase per machine being used to develop the project) but none of that will stop you from publishing your project on the app store or anywhere else and receiving commercial profit.  Such conditions are pretty rare, however, and possibly not enforceable per Unity's Asset Store EULA.

Per [Unity Asset Store EULA](https://unity3d.com/legal/as_provider), section 6.5:

> **Provider agrees that**, pursuant to the EULA, **it will grant to the Customer who acquires an Asset** submitted by the Provider, **a non-exclusive, worldwide, license in any medium** now known or hereinafter invented to: (a) reproduce, post, modify, promote, license, **sell**, publicly perform, publicly display, digitally perform, or transmit the Asset **for promotional and commercial purposes**; (b) use any trademarks, service marks or trade names incorporated in the Asset; and (c) use the name and likeness of any individuals represented in the Asset.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the asset developer states what kind of Licence the asset has. I tried finding the licence in for the assets you mentioned , but nothing mentioned it. I suggest emailing the developer and ask for his permission or/and the type of Licence his asset has.

Answer (score 0):

If it is free to use and no copyright are claimed, there is no restriction.